# Проверить запущен ли Steam

Tags: javascript

Как на `JS` можно узнать, запущен ли `Steam Client`?
Может как-то по ссылкам типа `steam://`?

Comment: Чего? Не понял суть вопроса? Что ты имеешь ввиду Steam Client? Программу стим на компе? Или через браузер?

Comment: Очень маловероятно. JS исполняется в песочнице браузера и к процессам системы, конечно, не имеет доступа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как на JS можно узнать, запущен ли Steam Client?

Нельзя. Нельзя даже узнать, установлен ли он. Если бы было можно, на стимовском сайте бы не было одновременно кнопок - "у меня есть стим" и "учтановить стим".

> Может как-то по ссылкам типа `steam://`?

Нет, оно обрабатываются браузером. После клика такой ссылки пользователем, стим может запуститься, но тоже не гарантированно: завистит от наличия стима и настроек браузера.

Answer (score 1):

браузер к файловой системе то доступа не имеет, а ты хочешь процессы проверять. никак не узнаешь